# How to implement addEventListener efficiently?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, user-interface, events

I'm developing a simple 2D browser game with canvas, but I've arrived at the point where I need to implement a simple user interface. Specifically, I have a hotbar that the user can click on to select an item. Clicking in the game world also uses your selected item at that location. So the current problem is that clicking the hotbar *also* causes it to click in the game world.

Instead, if the user clicks on the hotbar (just a rectangle drawn with canvas), I want the hotbar to handle that `mousedown` event and cause it to stop propagating upwards to the game canvas element, such that only the item is selected, and the item is not *also* used.

As a result, I developed a functionality akin to `addEventListener` for my custom user interface elements, but there is a problem: it's very slow.

For example, `mousedown` works well enough. When the user clicks at a location, it iterates through the parent hierarchy to find the element that is top-most, like this:

```
getTopMostElement(x, y) {
  let root = this.rootElement;

  for (let i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
    let child = root.children[i];
    let bounds = child.getBounds();

    if (bounds && rectangleContainsPoint(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.w, bounds.h, x, y)) {
      i = 0;
      root = child;
    }
  }

  return root;
}
```

It then checks if that element has a `mouseDown` listener, and if so, it calls it. If that listener called `stopPropagation`, then it stops propagating. Otherwise, it iterates up that element's parent hierarchy, calling each listener in turn.

The problem is with events like `mousemove`. This `O(n)` operation is simply too slow. That is, every time the user moves the mouse, it has to iterate down the entire element hierarchy to find the top-most element at the mouse position, and then iterate upwards. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? How do browsers do this? I only have 10-20 total UI elements at the moment, so I think even something like spatial partioning or spatial hashing wouldn't even be more efficient than a simple for loop.

Comment: you can create a treemap of the GUI maintaining on the treemap the "top-est" element in that point

Comment: or otherwise (more easily), an hashtable from pixel position to the the top-est element in that pixel (in js e.g. you can consider the pixels as consecutive, and use like `{0: obj, 1: obj}` and so when you have the mouse move you can use `hashtable[event.mouseY * pixelWidth + event.mouseX]`)... however this is very simplistic and you have to maintain that structure every time you change the GUI (add/remove elements)

Comment: Well you could use SVG instead of Canvas, which already handles hierarchical mapping implicitly.  But I’m guessing that ship already sailed…

Comment: Why not just use HTML on top of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, browsers have the advantage of being able to a) run native code and b) not have to deal with bindings between JS and native DOM elements to e.g. get the bounds/children/....

While I'm not entirely sure how browsers do this (although I'm sure you could find documentation or research papers about this), a few ideas that immediately come to mind:

- Have listener types be a linked list, where one handler points to the next one. This allows you to easily skip 30 levels in the hierarchy between element A and its descendant element B
- Divide your canvas in chunks and keep track of which elements are in which chunks. This makes it cheaper/faster to check whether a certain X/Y position is within the bounds of an element. E.g. if the element isn't even part of the chunk, there's no need to check its bounds anymore
- Very memory intensive, but you could keep for every pixel (or chunks of pixels) the most top-level element, making it very cheap to calculate the starting point (but of course, this is hard to keep track of)

You might be able to think of more optimizations since you know more of the details of your implementation. E.g. for mouse click/propagation, does it start at the most top-level element and then propagate through its ancestors? Or does it "propagate" through other elements at the same position? For example:

```
root           (z-index 0)
|- div A       (z-index 2)
|- div B       (z-index 1)
    |- button  (z-index 3)
```

Imagine that for some reason, you click an X/Y position where both div A, div B and the button are in bounds. Since the button is the most top-level rendered element, your event handling starts there. But where does it go next? `button > div B > root`? Or `button > div A > div B > root`? *e.g. propagate hierarchical or visual.* Decisions like that have an impact on how your "framework" works and in which ways you can optimize it.